# Как вывести 2х байтовый символ на PHP?

Tags: php

Хочу вывести смайл U+0263A

```
echo "\x26\x3A";  // выводит 2 обычных символа, &:
```

как выводить такие символы?

Comment: `echo "☺";` да и всё

Comment: Вообще этот символ 3х байтовый. `echo "\xe2\x98\xba"`. Потому что вы взяли код символа unicode, но вывод при этом происходит в UTF-8, в котором символ кодируется по специальным правилам (см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) или можно например воспользоваться какой нибудь таблицей вроде https://unicode-table.com/ru/263A/

Comment: @Mike мой внутренний телепат очень сильно подозревает, что автор использует вообще какой-нибудь cp1251

Comment: твой телепат ошибся) я не настолько глуп, @mike спасибо то что надо